# JPA Query For Exists In

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have the following Entities (reduced and renamed for this example)

```
@Entity
public class Case {

@Id
private Long id;


@ManyToOne(optional=false)
private CourtConfiguration courtConfiguration;

@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<String> caseNumbers;

}
```

Second Entity

```
@Entity
public class CourtConfiguration {

@Id
private Long id;

String countyId;

String referenceId;

.... 

}
```

I am trying to search using *JPQL* for all Cases that have a certain courtConfiguration countyId and have caseNumbers containing all of a provided set of important caseNumbers.

So my query needs the countyId and set of caseNumbers as parameters. Called countyId and importantCaseNumbers respectively.

I have tried and failed to get it to work.

My query looks like this

```
String query = "SELECT case FROM Case case JOIN case.caseNumbers caseNumbers WHERE ";
query       += "case.caseConfiguration.countyId = :countyId ";
```

The bit above works until I add my caseNumber conditions.
I have tried a foreach importantNumbers to extend the query and as soon as the list of important numbers goes above one it doesn't work. No values get returned.

```
for (String importantCaseNum : importantCaseNumbers) {
    query += " AND '"+importantCaseNum+"' in (caseNumbers)";
}
```

Any suggestions/pointers appreciated. I guess what I am looking for is a case.caseNumbers contains (importantNumbers) clause.

**Update** I have reverted to native SQL for my query as I didn't want to tie myself into hibernate by using HQL. Thanks to @soulcheck and @mikko for helping me out. I'll post up when the hibernate JPA fix is available.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work". Exception? No values returned?

Comment: Can you post the code where you used foreach?

Comment: I updated the question to take into account a JOIN I hadn't included in the sample. Thanks for taking the time to help. I'll post the for each next.

Comment: Strange that is stops only if you add contitions. Are you sure you have any Case which has all necesarry importantCaseNumbers? Also maybe try MEMBER OF instead of IN.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback MEMBER OF doesn't seem to work I am getting [main] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
[main] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - <AST>:0:0: expecting "from", found '<ASTNULL>' seems to be a known issue with @ElementCollection https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5209.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically correct way to build this JPQL query is with MEMBER OF. But because of problem reported in [HHH-5209](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5209) it doesn't work with old Hibernate versions (fix version 4.1.8, 4.3.0.Beta1). According bug report HQL version of this query works, so your options includes at least:

1. Using JPQL query and switching to some other JPA implementation
2. Using HQL instead and sticking with Hibernate:

   query += " AND '"+importantCaseNum+"' in elements(caseNumbers)";

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Mikko I appreciate it, I spotted the bug report before, hopefully the issue will be fixed in a new version. I'll post up when its fixed I am watching the bug report for updates.

Comment: link is no longer valid

Comment: Updated link to current Hibernate bug tracking tool.